# Which FreeBSD version or ISO for Dell R310?

Tags: install, freebsd, distribution-choice, architecture

When I try to install FreeBSD I always get confused as to which iso is the correct one for Rack mounted servers. In [their download choices](http://www.freebsd.org/platforms/), there are too many versions of FreeBSD

Which one is the correct one to burn in CDROM or USB drive to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is [look up the processor architecture](http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/poweredge-r310/pd.aspx?refid=poweredge-r310&cs=555&s=biz). This is an intel processor of the x86 family, supporting 64-bit mode (you can see this very clearly in the list of supported operating systems, for example). So you need either i386 or amd64.

Almost all current servers, and most desktops for that matter, have amd64 processors anyway (also known as x86_64 or a number of variations, not to be confused with ia64 which is completely different). All amd64 processors also support i386 instructions.

Comment: Thank you Gilles. Also this is nice tutorial i found to get started quickly e.g: http://youtu.be/GVT1Ee3Xw80